# Im unable to read the redux store outside of mapStateToProps function in a component. (For example in a render() )

Tags: reactjs, redux

Im using react like this

Firstly I load the store with mapStateToProps. And inside that function im actually able to read the store. The object that is read there is basically the same as the `this.state.renderedEl` , but with different values.
**My goal is to delete that state, and use the store values instead**.

Those values should be read in the render() where Im actually using the `this.state.renderedEl` values to evaluate some conditions. But I dont undestand how to read the store values instead

```
        import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
    import brand from "../images/valhallaNaranja.png";
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

    import { faArrowAltCircleLeft, faArrowAltCircleRight, faUser } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
    import { faColumns } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
    import './css/Sidebar.css'
    import { isAdmin } from "../services/userCheck.js"
    import { connect } from "react-redux";


    const mapStateToProps = state => {
//I CAN READ THE STORE THERE
        console.log("-sidebar-")
            console.log(state.renderedEl)
        console.log("-sidebar-")
        return { renderedEl: state.renderedEl }
    }

    class SideBar extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                retracted: this.props.retracted,
                isAdmin: false,
                isHovering: false,
//I WANT TO STOP USING THIS SO I CAN USE THE STORE DATA
                renderedEl: {
                    heimdall: false,
                    skadi: false,
                    mercator: false
                }
            }

            this.hoverTrue = this.hoverTrue.bind(this);
            this.hoverFalse = this.hoverFalse.bind(this);
        }



        componentDidMount() {
            if (isAdmin()) {
                this.setState({
                    isAdmin: true
                })
            }
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
            if (this.state.retracted != this.props.retracted) {
                this.setState({
                    retracted: this.props.retracted
                })
            }
        }

        renderEl = (el) => {
            var elementName = el.target.getAttribute('id');
            var renderedElements = this.state.renderedEl;

            for (let key in renderedElements) {
                if (key == elementName) {
                    renderedElements[key] = true
                }
            }

            this.setState({
                renderEl: renderedElements
            })


        }

        hoverTrue() {
            this.setState({
                isHovering: true
            })
        }

        hoverFalse() {
            this.setState({
                isHovering: false
            })
        }

        render() {

            let navbar_brand = this.state.retracted ? "navbar-brand-retracted" : "navbar-brand";
            let img_redie = this.state.retracted ? "img-redie-retracted" : "img-redie";
            let home_icon = this.state.retracted ? "divicon homeicon-retracted" : "divicon homeicon";
            let register_icon = this.state.retracted ? "divicon divicon2 registericon-retracted" : "divicon divicon2 registericon";
            let expand_icon = this.state.retracted ? "divicon-no-hover divicon2 expandicon-retracted" : "divicon divicon2 expandicon";
            //I WANT TO READ THE STORE THERE, INSTEAD OF THE STATE VALUES
            let skadiRendered = this.state.renderedEl.skadi ? "bubbletext bubbletext-rendered" : "bubbletext";
            let heimdallRendered = this.state.renderedEl.heimdall ? "bubbletext bubbletext-rendered" : "bubbletext";
            let mercatorRendered = this.state.renderedEl.mercator ? "bubbletext bubbletext-rendered" : "bubbletext";

            let layoutAppVisualSelector = this.props.history.location.pathname == "/layout" ? "divicon divicon2 expandicon divicon-layout" : "divicon divicon2 expandicon";
            return (
                <div id="sidebar" className={this.state.retracted ? 'sidebar-retracted' : 'sidebar-expanded'}>
                    <div /*routerLink=""*/ className={navbar_brand}>
                        <img alt="Reddie" src={brand} width="60" height="60" className={img_redie} />
                    </div>

                    <ul className="nav nav3 navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            {/* Home icon */}
                            <div className={home_icon} onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/')}>
                                <svg className="svgicon-sidebar" viewBox="0 0 14 14" >
                                    <path d="M13.9 5.7L7.2.8c-.1-.1-.3-.1-.4 0L.1 5.7c-.1.1-.1.3 0 .5s.3.2.5.1L7 1.6l6.4 4.7c.1 0 .1.1.2.1s.2-.1.3-.1c.1-.3.1-.5 0-.6" />
                                    <path d="M12.1 6.4c-.2 0-.4.2-.4.4v5.8H8.8V9.4c0-1-.8-1.8-1.8-1.8s-1.8.8-1.8 1.8v3.2H2.3V6.7c0-.2-.2-.4-.4-.4s-.4.2-.4.4v6.2c0 .2.2.4.4.4h3.6c.2 0 .3-.1.4-.3V9.4c0-.6.5-1.1 1.1-1.1.6 0 1.1.5 1.1 1.1v3.5c0 .2.2.3.4.3h3.6c.2 0 .4-.2.4-.4V6.7c0-.2-.2-.3-.4-.3" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        {this.state.isAdmin ? <li>
                            <div className={register_icon} onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/admin')}>
                                <FontAwesomeIcon className="registerIcon" icon={faUser} />
                            </div>
                        </li> : null}


                        {(this.props.history.location.pathname != "/layout") && (this.props.history.location.pathname != "/skadi") && (this.props.history.location.pathname != "/heimdall") && (this.props.history.location.pathname != "/mercator") ? null : <li>
                            <div className={layoutAppVisualSelector} onMouseEnter={this.hoverTrue}
                                onMouseLeave={this.hoverFalse} >
                                <FontAwesomeIcon className="registerIcon" icon={faColumns} onClick={() => this.props.history.push({ pathname: '/layout', state: { comeFrom: this.props.history.location.pathname } })} />
                                {(this.state.isHovering && this.props.history.location.pathname == "/layout") ? <div className="speech-bubble" onMouseLeave={this.hoverFalse}
                                    onMouseEnter={this.hoverTrue}>
                                    <span id="heimdall" className={heimdallRendered} onClick={(el) => this.renderEl(el)}>Heimdall</span> <br /> <span className={skadiRendered} id="skadi" onClick={(el) => this.renderEl(el)}>Skadi</span> <br /> <span id="mercator" className={mercatorRendered} onClick={(el) => this.renderEl(el)}>Mercator</span>
                                </div> : null}

                            </div>

                        </li>}

                        {(this.state.retracted) || ((this.props.history.location.pathname == "/") || (this.props.history.location.pathname == "/register")) || (this.props.history.location.pathname == "/admin") || (this.props.history.location.pathname == "/layout") ? null : <li>
                            <div className="divicon divicon2 expandicon " onClick={this.props.retract}>
                                <FontAwesomeIcon className="registerIcon" icon={faArrowAltCircleLeft} />
                            </div>
                        </li>}



                    </ul>

                    {this.state.retracted ? <div className="expandicon-retracted-container"> <FontAwesomeIcon className="expandicon-retracted" icon={faArrowAltCircleRight} onClick={this.props.unretract} /> </div> : null}

                </div>

            )
        }

    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SideBar)
```

Comment: Do you understand what the `mapStateToProps` function does? It's right in the name. You'll have a prop named `renderedEl` with the value from state. `this.props.renderedEl`.

Comment: @DrewReese i actually wasnt aware, that did the trick too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        retracted: this.props.retracted,
        isAdmin: false,
        isHovering: false,
        renderedEl: {
            heimdall: false,
            skadi: false,
            mercator: false
        }
    }
    store.subscribe(() => {
        this.setState({
            renderedEl: store.getState().renderedEl
        }, () =>{
            console.log("subscribed")
            console.log(this.state.renderedEl)
        })
    })



    this.hoverTrue = this.hoverTrue.bind(this);
    this.hoverFalse = this.hoverFalse.bind(this);
}



componentDidMount() {
    if (isAdmin()) {
        this.setState({
            isAdmin: true
        })
    }

    this.setState({
        renderedEl: store.getState().renderedEl
    })
}
```